# Why replaceAll method is not working?

Tags: java, file-io, replaceall, file.readalllines

I read from file like this:

```
List<String> list = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("file.csv"));
```

After that I try to call `replaceAll` method on every string in the list, but it doesn't work with any regex and replacement string. Although, when I apply `replaceAll` with the same arguments to a string that I assign in code, it works fine.
The strings look like this: `"Hello","World","!!!"`

#### Edit:

```
List<String> res = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("TimeTable.csv"));

String p = "^\"(\\w+) (\\w+) (\\w+) (?:.+)?\",\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\",\"(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)\"(?:.*?)$/i";
String rep = "$6-$5-$4 ==> $7:$8 $1 $2 $3";
String s = res.get(1).replaceAll(p, rep);
System.out.print(s);
```

The file consists of strings like that:

```
"AK Pz 310u PI-13-5","23.02.2015","07:45:00","23.02.2015","09:20:00","False","True","23.02.2015","07:40:00","2","Common","AK Pz 310u PI-13-5","Common"
```

Here is the exact code I'm using: http://pastebin.com/GhhrRWAU

And here is the file I'm trying to parse: http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g450e5a3e83854bdc999643999f2ceb8c622d6abf2

Comment: Please show your code that performs the `replaceAll`.

Comment: Add some code. It will be easier to understand.

Comment: Sounds like you call `replaceAll` without writing the result back to the list? (Just a guess.)

Comment: Your code behaves the same for me whether I read that line in from a file, or assign it in-line (no replacement happens).  Can you please show us the code where you assign the string in the code and it works?  Perhaps you aren't escaping the `"` or something?

Comment: When I assign the string in the code I do escape all quotes

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`RegEx` is always a headache for me, too. Actually your regex expression is almost correct (you can check it on https://regex101.com/, for example). But this is `Java` and you should use inline modifier:

```
String p = "^\"(\\w+) (\\w+) (\\w+) (?:.+)?\",\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\",\"(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)\"(?:.*?)$";
String rep = "$6-$5-$4 ==> $7:$8 $1 $2 $3";
String test = "\"AK Pz 310u PI-13-5\",\"23.02.2015\",\"07:45:00\",\"23.02.2015\",\"09:20:00\",\"False\",\"True\",\"23.02.2015\",\"07:40:00\",\"2\",\"Common\",\"AK Pz 310u PI-13-5\",\"Common\"";
String s = test.replaceAll(p, rep);
System.out.print(s);
```

Output:

```
2015-02-23 ==> 07:40 AK Pz 310u
```

BTW, `\i` modifier is useless here, because `\w` already matches `[a-zA-Z0-9_]`

**EDIT** Your file contains non-Latin characters, so you can use `Regex` groups instead:

```
List<String> res = Files.readAllLines(Paths.get("TimeTable.csv"));
String p = "(?i)^\"([\\p{L}_]+) (\\p{L}+) ([\\p{L}\\p{N}-_]+) (?:.+)?\",\"(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\\.(\\d+)\",\"(\\d+):(\\d+):(\\d+)\"(?:.*?)$";
String rep = "$6-$5-$4 ==> $7:$8 $1 $2 $3";
for (String str : res){
    System.out.println(str.replaceAll(p, rep));
}
```

Comment: it didn't work for me, unfortunately... And the cool trick is that on regex101.com everything works super fine, but not in code

Comment: @DenisYakovenko please check once again the pattern I've written carefully. Did you remove `/i` from the end? Here is a proof, that it works as expected https://ideone.com/W6Hv5Y.

Comment: Yes, your exapmle worked with the string assigned in the code. Although it doesn't work with the same strings from file

Comment: Here I've hosted the file I'm trying to use:
http://www.fileconvoy.com/dfl.php?id=g450e5a3e83854bdc999643999f2ceb8c622d6abf2
And here is the exact code that I'm using:
http://pastebin.com/GhhrRWAU

Comment: maybe it doesn't work with file because the file contains ciryllic values?

Comment: @DenisYakovenko definitely yes, because `\w` matches Latin characters. I suggest you to use `Regex` groups instead. I've updated my answer with new pattern.

Answer (score 1):

> After that I try to call replaceAll method on every string in the list

The `replaceAll()` method does not update the existing String. It creates a new String.

So you need to update the List with your newly created String:

```
String testing = "some text";
//testing.replaceAll(...); // this doesn't work
testing = testing.replaceAll(....);
```

Comment: @DenisYakovenko Is that so?